# What is the best free/paid C++ Video Training resource out there?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources

I'm a .NET Developer, primarily using c#, asp.net mvc, entity framework and programming for the Web. I want to know what you guys recommend to get a quick startup in learning c++. My biggest worries are pointers, memory management and other languages differences between managed and native languages. I want to know if there is some video training resource like Dimecasts and Tekpub for .NET.
Thanks :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XoaX.net](http://www.XoaX.net) best video resource I've found so far. I Suggest you guys take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Does it really have to be a video?

The problem with C++ is that there are a lot of people that claim to know it, but instead they use it like "C with object oriented programming" or simply don't use it like it was meant to be used.

I have never found a resource better than Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" which you can find pretty much everywhere. Written by the creator of the language, it is pretty much the definitive source, and it will take you from the beginning through all the details, *the way it was meant to be.*

Answer (score 2):

This one is pretty good
http://www.mixsoftware.com/product/cpvideo.htm
But generally video lectures for C++ are not as good as learning from a book and practically learning using an IDE.

There are plenty of questions which give you the best resources for learning C++ with this one being the most useful 
[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Are you sure you are looking only for video leactures and not books.

Comment: From the first link: "Since C++ is an extension of the C language, it is recommended that you learn C before attempting to learn C++." Stroustrup strongly disagrees about that!

Comment: Well guys, is there a since I'm coming from .net? I want video training because I have to get it VERY fast. Maybe I'll not have time to read an entirely book at the first moment.

Comment: If you're looking for a "quick fix" then C++ is not the language for you. If you don't learn it right, you're not only going to shoot your foot off, you're going to take the rest of your leg with it.

Comment: I love pluralsight for most of their videos, but the c++ videos are pretty bad, I have to stick with the books for C++ i have found thus far